# nginx+uwsgi+django, how to configure 404.html and 502.html

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I close debug mode, and I see a default 502 Error when I visit a non-exsit page.

I have put 404.html, 403.html, 502.html in my project, but I still can't see these pages, the project works all well except this part, what should i config about this problem ?

My configuration below:

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name 119.254.35.221;
location /{
uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT www.wsgi;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /root/www;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /root/www;
uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
}
}
```

The project tree:

```
[root@vps616 www]# pwd
/root/www
[root@vps616 www]# ll
total 1036
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 28 11:05 books
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     246 Sep 27 13:29 manage.py
-rw------- 1 root root    6228 Sep 28 09:56 nohup.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      41 Sep 27 23:54 restart.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      53 Sep 28 16:51 start.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 28 20:18 static
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     217 Sep 28 14:05 uwsgi.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     272 Sep 27 23:16 uwsgi.xml.backup
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Sep 28 20:27 www
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1009290 Sep 28 20:25 www.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root       6 Sep 28 16:48 www.pid
[root@vps616 www]# ll www
total 48
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 28 20:27 403.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 28 20:18 404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  227 Sep 28 17:01 forms.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 27 13:29 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112 Sep 28 08:46 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5247 Sep 28 20:20 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2924 Sep 28 20:20 settings.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 28 17:04 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  630 Sep 28 16:47 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  641 Sep 28 11:03 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  625 Sep 28 17:22 views.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  871 Sep 28 11:03 views.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1126 Sep 28 12:32 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1000 Sep 28 12:32 wsgi.pyc
[root@vps616 www]#
```

The uwsgi config:

```
[root@vps616 www]# cat uwsgi.ini 
[uwsgi]  
uid = 500
listen=200
master = true  
profiler = true 
processes = 8 
logdate = true  
pidfile = /root/www/www.pid  
daemonize = /root/www/www.log  
enable-threads = true
memory-report = true
limit-as = 6048
```

start command:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini -s 127.0.0.1:8000
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the thing you actually want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the 404.html, etc... files inside your template directory (where you have your base_site.html if you have)

Comment: another question is : how to configure nginx to show staic files in /root/www/static, thanks a lot, waiting here..

Comment: Make an example please, why have you got to show static files? Which kind of static files? the static directory in django projects usally contains static resources like css, javascript, images...

I use this inside server part of nginx configuration:

location /static {

                root  /abs/path/to/the/web/root/;

                expires max;
 }

the important part is root...., and clearly I have all my static files collected inside a static directory which stays exactly inside the site web root.

Comment: I also put the static files in nginx itself, the config like this, but i found that the http request goes to the uwsgi but not the nginx itself, what mistakes did i make ? thank you..server{
listen 80;
server_name 119.254.35.221;

location ^~ /static {
root /root/www;
}

location /{
uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT www.wsgi;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /root/www;
uwsgi_param UWSGI_PYHOME /root/www;
uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";
}
}

Comment: and the nginx access log is : 2012/09/28 21:32:23 [error] 19969#0: *24 open() "/root/www/static/aa.html" failed , the uri is correct, but it goes to location /, not the /static/xxx

Comment: this is the part of virtual host configuration I used: http://pastebin.com/hwpDj50B    You use this (location ^~ /static), try to use only location /static ...

Comment: I have tried to use localtion /static, still not work... I follow your configure by adding root to both location, but it still doesn't work. Strange problem, why always to the uwsgi... any other possibles..

Comment: now it works? if not use pastebin and attach the complete virtual host configuration and folder structure of you project